Proving state sequence properties through sets
I have recursive datatype state and several operations on it:
datatype state = 
  emptyState 
  | toEnv state
  | setVarBool state variable bool 
  | setVarInt state variable int
  | setVarNat state variable nat
  | setVarReal state variable real
  | setPstate state process pstate 
  | reset state process

primrec substate:: "state ⇒ state ⇒ bool" where
"substate s emptyState =
 (if s = emptyState then True else False)" 
| "substate s (toEnv s1) =
  (if s = toEnv s1 then True else substate s s1)" 
| "substate s (setVarBool s1 v u) = 
  (if s = setVarBool s1 v u then True else substate s s1)" 
| "substate s (setVarInt s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarInt s1 v u then True else substate s s1)"
| "substate s (setVarNat s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarNat s1 v u then True else substate s s1)"
| "substate s (setVarReal s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarReal s1 v u then True else substate s s1)"
| "substate s (setPstate s1 p q) =
  (if s = setPstate s1 p q then True else substate s s1)" 
| "substate s (reset s1 p) =
  (if s = reset s1 p then True else substate s s1)"

primrec toEnvNum:: "state ⇒state ⇒ nat" where 
"toEnvNum s emptyState = 0" 
| "toEnvNum s (toEnv s1) = 
  (if s = toEnv s1 then 0 else toEnvNum s s1 + 1)" 
| "toEnvNum s (setVarBool s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarBool s1 v u then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)" 
| "toEnvNum s (setVarInt s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarInt s1 v u then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)" 
| "toEnvNum s (setVarNat s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarNat s1 v u then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)"
| "toEnvNum s (setVarReal s1 v u) =
  (if s = setVarReal s1 v u then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)"
| "toEnvNum s (setPstate s1 p q) = 
  (if s = setPstate s1 p q then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)" 
| "toEnvNum s (reset s1 p) =
  (if s = reset s1 p then 0 else toEnvNum s s1)"

fun toEnvP::"state ⇒ bool" where
"toEnvP (toEnv _) = True" 
| "toEnvP _ = False"

primrec predEnv:: "state ⇒ state" where
"predEnv emptyState = emptyState" 
| "predEnv (toEnv s) =
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)" 
| "predEnv (setVarBool s _ _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)" 
| "predEnv (setVarInt s _ _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)"
| "predEnv (setVarNat s _ _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)"
| "predEnv (setVarReal s _ _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)"
| "predEnv (setPstate s _ _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)" 
| "predEnv (reset s _) = 
  (if (toEnvP s) then s else predEnv s)"

primrec shiftEnv:: "state ⇒ nat ⇒ state" where
"shiftEnv s 0 = s" |
"shiftEnv s (Suc n) = predEnv (shiftEnv s n)"

I usually need to prove some lemmas about properties of sequential env states (i.e. s1 = predEnv s2), where properties have form P s = ∀s'. toEnvP s' ∧ substate s' s ∧ Q s' ⟶ R s' (sometimes there are properties with several variables under quantifier). I have P s1 as assumption and proofed case when s'=s2. Sometimes it enough to automatically proof P s2, but sometimes not.
I tried to generalize this through transforming state into state set and proving lemmas on it:
fun state_to_set :: "state ⇒ (state set)" where
"state_to_set emptyState = {emptyState}"
| "state_to_set (toEnv s) = insert (toEnv s) (state_to_set (predEnv (toEnv s)))"
 
definition Ball_one:: "state set ⇒ (state⇒bool) ⇒ bool" where
"Ball_one s P = Ball s P"

lemma substate_set:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
    and "x∈(state_to_set s)"
  shows "substate x s"
proof ???

lemma set_prop_extend:
  fixes P::"state⇒state⇒bool"
  assumes "toEnvP s1"
  and "toEnvP s2"
  and "Ball_one (state_to_set s1) (P s1)"
  and "(P s2 s2)"
  and "s1 = predEnv s2"
shows "Ball_one (state_to_set s1) (P s2)" 
proof ???

As I understand, lemma set_prop_extend should be true because third assumption shows property is true for every env substates of s1, fourth shows property is true for case s'= s2, fifth shows that there is no env substates between s1 s2, and in the end I want to show that property is true is right for every env substate of s2.
I ask for help with proving these lemmas or maybe some better way of conceptualization and proving such properties.
Some additional lemmas which could help:
lemma substate_refl: "substate s s"
  apply(cases s)
         apply(auto)
  done

(*substate_trans and substate_asym are proved, it just takes to much space*)
lemma substate_trans:
"substate s1 s2 ∧ substate s2 s3 ⟹ substate s1 s3" by sorry
lemma substate_asym:
 "substate s1 s2 ∧ substate s2 s1 ⟹ s1=s2" by sorry

lemma predEnv_substate: "substate (predEnv s) s"
  apply(induction s)
  using substate_refl  by auto

lemma substate_eq_or_predEnv: 
"substate s1 s2 ∧ toEnvP s1 ⟶ s1=s2 ∨ substate s1 (predEnv s2)"
  apply(induction s2)
         apply(auto)
  done

lemma substate_total: 
"substate s1 s ∧ substate s2 s ⟶
 substate s1 s2 ∨ substate s2 s1"
  apply(induction s)
         apply(auto)
  done

lemma toEnvNum_id: "toEnvNum s s = 0"
  apply(cases s)
         apply(auto)
  done

lemma substate_toEnvNum_id:
"substate s1 s2 ∧ toEnvNum s1 s2 = 0 ∧ toEnvP s1 ∧
toEnvP s2 ⟶ s1=s2"
  apply(cases s2)
         apply(auto)
  done

lemma gtime_predI:
 "¬ toEnvP s ⟹   toEnvNum emptyState s =
 toEnvNum emptyState (predEnv s)"
  apply(induction s)
         apply(auto)
  done

lemma self_set:
  assumes "toEnvP s1"
  shows "s1 ∈ state_to_set s1"
  using state_to_set.simps assms toEnvP.elims(2) by fastforce

lemma predEnv_set:
  assumes "toEnvP s1"
  shows "predEnv s1 ∈ state_to_set s1" 
by (metis assms insertI1 insert_commute predEnvP_or_emptyState state_to_set.simps(1) state_to_set.simps(2) toEnvP.elims(2))
lemma state_to_set_wrap:
"toEnvP s ⟹ state_to_set s = state_to_set (predEnv (toEnv s))"
  apply auto
  done

lemma state_to_set_state_sep:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
  shows "state_to_set s = insert s (state_to_set (predEnv s))"
  by (metis assms state_to_set.simps(2) state_to_set_wrap toEnvP.elims(2))

lemma state_to_set_subset:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
  and "toEnvP s'"
  and "s = predEnv s'"
shows "(state_to_set s) ⊆ (state_to_set s')"
  using assms(2) assms(3) state_to_set_state_sep by auto
lemma set_extend:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
  and "toEnvP s'"
  and "s = predEnv s'"
shows "state_to_set s' = insert s' (state_to_set s)"
  by (metis assms(2) assms(3) state_to_set.simps(2) toEnvP.elims(2))

lemma shiftEnv_in_set:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
  shows "shiftEnv s 1 ∈ state_to_set s"
proof -
  have 1:"shiftEnv s 1 = predEnv s" by simp
  have 2:"predEnv s ∈ state_to_set s" using assms predEnv_set by simp
  show ?thesis using 1 2 by auto
qed

lemma state_in_set:
  assumes "toEnvP s"
  shows "s ∈ state_to_set s" 
  by (metis assms insertCI state_to_set.simps(2) toEnvP.elims(2))

lemma predEnv_shiftEnv_swap:
"predEnv (shiftEnv s n) = (shiftEnv (predEnv s) n)"
  apply (induction n)
   apply auto
  done

lemma emptyState_shiftEnv: "shiftEnv emptyState n = emptyState"
  apply (induction n)
   apply auto
  done

lemma shiftEnv_unwarp:
"shiftEnv s (n+1) = shiftEnv (predEnv s) n"
  apply (induction n)
   apply auto
  done

